# CCLiquid effect on a specific area of CCSprite?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Developing an iPhone game with Cocos2d-iphone. I have a huge sprite and I want to apply a CCLiquid (or any other liquid-wave-like effect) on it.

However, the image is huge, so it consumes a lot of memory (without mentioning I have many other big elements during gameplay).

Well, I figured I could try to "only apply the liquid effect on the area that is visible by the player" (dimensions of such area being 480x320). That could help a lot.

I already got a CGRect representing the area of the CCSprite that should be affected. However, how would I actually apply the effect *only within such area*? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually create a CCSprite from a sprite frame and set the boundaries of that frame to your CGRect. Then use the effect on this resulting CCSprite. Essentially, your original CCSprite image would act like a larger texture atlas form which you are specifying a small portion of that image to be the actual frame of your sprite. If you layered this new copied sprite on top of your main, larger one in the exact position, it would appear to be part of that larger sprite, but only the small CGRect portion would be affected by your code.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to do that yesterday and it did improve things. But I still wanted to do it in the same sprite... anyway, good enough.